# What will happen in this situation?

Tags: c++

Say I have base class A. it has method

```
void foo(A* a);
```

It also has method

```
void foo(B* b);
```

B inherits from A.

Say I now have a B instance but it is an A* ex:

```
A* a = new B();
```

If I were to call

```
 someA.foo(a);
```

Would this call the A* implementation or B* implementation of the method?

I'm providing an A* to the method, but what that object actually is is a B().

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just add some logging to the `foo` functions, try and see?

Comment: @Xeo: Indeed, teach a fish...

Comment: @Xeo, that would explain the *what* but not the *why*.

Comment: @Mark: Well, that is another question. The title explicitly states *what*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, two things will happen. First of all the determination of which function to call:

```
A* a = new B();
foo(a);
```

Here you pass a variable of type A* (C++ = static typed, remember) to foo, this will as usual call `foo(A* a)`, nothing different from any other function overloading. If you were to call `foo(new B())` it would use the implicit type `B*` and end up calling `foo(B* b)`. Nothing new here, plain old function overloading. Note that only when `foo(B*)` is not present it will fall back to a more generic version because of inheritance.

Now in your example we come to the calling of this function:

```
void foo(A* a)
{
    a->foo();
}
```

Well, again, standard C++ calling conventions apply, including polymorphism. This means if you have declared foo as virtual the vtable will be constructed in such a way that the foo method of B will be called for your example (as the object is created as type B). If `A::foo()` is not declared as virtual, the method of A itself will be called.

Answer (score 6):

Function overloads are selected based on the *static type* of the passed parameter. The *static type* of `a` is `A*`, only its *dynamic type* is `B`. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect it to use the `foo(A *)` method because the static type is `A`.

But, like someone said, add some logging and try checking which one is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Because `A::foo(A*)` and `B::foo(B*)` have different signatures (types of their arguments), the compiler treats them as totally different functions. If instead of calling both methods `foo()` you had called one `A::bar(A*)` and another `B::baz(B*)`, you would get identical behavior.

`foo(A*)` is a method of all objects of type `A`, and all objects of type `B` are also objects of type `A` because `B` is derived from `A`. So `foo()` is indeed a method of the object `someA`, inherited from the parent `A` class.  This method, the `A` method, is the one that gets called.